# why isnt the print result in myprog.py printed in alice1.py?

Tags: python

myprog.py:

```
def sum1(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
    print ("Sum is ", sum1(3,6))
```

alice1.py:

```
import myprog
num = 10
total = num + myprog.sum1(23, 12)
print ("Alice total is ", total)
```

I thought that if I run alice1.py, the print output in prgm1.py should also be shown

Comment: The print statement is never reached since you `return c` before it

Comment: You should use an IDE, any decent IDE will warn you that some code is not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

In the function sum1(), the moment the line

```
return c
```

is executed control is returned back to alice1.py. So the next line will never be executed.

The print statement should be placed before the return.

Also use

```
print("Sum is ", c)
```

instead of calling sum1()

Answer (score 0):

Python will not execute a line after the `return` command, so you should use the `print` function before the `return` command. Here is your full code

"my.prog.py"

```
def sum1(a, b):
    c = a + b
    print ("Sum is ", sum1(3,6))
    return c
```

"alice1.py"

```
import myprog
num = 10
total = num + myprog.sum1(23, 12)
print ("Alice total is ", total)
# this will print 35
```

Don't forget to check my Programming Language here "https://github.com/Faran2007/FSCMD"